# python mysql insert float number accuracy

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I'm encountering a problem of inserting a float number into mysql with Python 3.7.7, MariaDB V15.1, mysql python package 0.0.2.

For example, my structure of table and Python code is like:

```
  `total` float(24,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

```
import mysql.connector as mc

db = mc.connect(host, user, password, database..)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into mytable (data_id, total) values (4, 29147.17)")
db.commit()
```

As a result, in the database, where it should be 29147.17, it says like 29147.16992. And the next time when I select from the database, the value is 29147.16992, missing the accuracy of data.

Any advice that I can save the original data into the database? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to change the type of 'value' in database from float(24,5) to decimal(24,5), then the inserted data will be 29147.17000, and 'select' it in Python gives result of decimal.Decimal('29147.17000'), and then I will float() it to get a float number. This sounds a little complex, but working. But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to address this issue. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: why do you need it as a float in python? Because decimal is the correct way to store a precise number.

Comment: because the project has been using float for all calculation, and AFAIK decimal doesn't support calculation with float numbers. any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please modify your mysql table field to DECIMAL

```
`total` DECIMAL(24,5) DEFAULT NULL,   `data_id` int(11) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Insert again through the python program and you will get the same precision value.